# Lyx and biblatex-chicago notes not formatting properly natively

Tags: biblatex, citing, lyx, footnotes, biblatex-chicago

I’m trying to get LyX working properly for my different work related documents. I’ve been using the `biblatex-chicago` package with LaTeX and it works great.

However, with LyX, once I configured everything correctly in the document preferences (*i.e.*, `chicago-notes` for inline citations, `chicago-notes` for bibliography, running `biber`, etc.) it **does** give me the correct citation style at first, but if I cite subsequently the same citation, it gives me the full bibliographic notes, while it should shorten it to only print the author, short title, and page number.

[image]

Here is the result expected:
[image]

There is a workaround. That is, when citing, in the dialog box, in citation style, we can choose either `footnote: full bibliography entry` or `footnote: $author, $date`.

[image]

However, that is really not efficient as we have to remember when if we just cited it or not, and it truly slows down the workflow.

What I don’t understand, is that the `biblatex-chicago` package handles that very well all by himself, so why LyX does not?

Is the package not loaded already? And if so, why it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @moewe’s solution does work (and you answer the question of why it doesn’t work as intended with LyX), I would like to point out to another solution that I believe work better.

I would have preferred not to fiddle with the preamble in LyX, but since @moewe solution does it anyway, I figured that I could implement the `biblatex-chicago` package directly in the preamble.

Thus, I use this:

```latex
\usepackage[notes,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}

%%%%%%%%%%%optional%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}
```

Then, using `autocite` command in LyX works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-chicago` is a bit special. Ideally its styles should not be loaded via `\usepackage[style=...]{biblatex}`. Instead you should use the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago`

```
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
```

This wrapper package sets style options and loads auxiliary packages.

Unfortunately, you can't select the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago` in the LyX bibliography/citation dialogue. So we need to do the work that `\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}` normally does manually.

Here is what I did

1. In *Document Settings > Bibliography* select "Style format: Biblatex"
2. Set both "Biblatex citation style" and "Biblatex bibliography style" to `chicago-notes`.
3. Paste the following into the "Options" field

   ```
   pagetracker=true, autocite=footnote,abbreviate=false,alldates=comp, citetracker=true,ibidtracker=constrict,usetranslator=true, usenamec=true,loccittracker=constrict,dateabbrev=false, maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sorting=cms,sortcase=false, labeltitle=true,alltimes=12h,urltime=24h,timezones=true, datezeros=false,datecirca=true,dateuncertain=true,compressyears=true, nodates=true,uniquename=minfull,
   ```

This gives

[image: Screenshot of the settings just described]

Then

4. In *Document Settings > LaTeX Preamble* add

   ```
   \usepackage{xstring}
   ```

[image: Preamble settings with \usepackage{xstring}]

Now configure your bibliography as usual and add citations with `\autocite`

[image: Citation dialogue]

The following `.lxy` file works for me

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_options pagetracker=true, autocite=footnote,abbreviate=false,alldates=comp, citetracker=true,ibidtracker=constrict,usetranslator=true, usenamec=true,loccittracker=constrict,dateabbrev=false, maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sorting=cms,sortcase=false, labeltitle=true,alltimes=12h,urltime=24h,timezones=true, datezeros=false,datecirca=true,dateuncertain=true,compressyears=true, nodates=true,uniquename=minfull,
\biblatex_bibstyle chicago-notes
\biblatex_citestyle chicago-notes
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
Lorem
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand autocite
key "sigfridsson"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
ipsum 
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand autocite
key "sigfridsson"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintCited"
bibfiles "biblatex-examples"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```